# Assembling PCB - C and R holes are touching

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly

Silly question. I am assembling a PCB. The holes for R3 and C29 (center right) are touching each other. Is this correct?

[image: pcb]

[image]

Comment: It might be. We can't be sure without a schematic.

Comment: Many thanks. I didn’t know this was potentially valid. Will find schematic. (I assume it is correct).

Comment: It surely looks like it's meant to be connected.

Comment: Updated to include schematic with R3 and C29

Comment: Buzz out the right side of R3 to see if it connects to IC17:5.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to avoid having component pads that close, but it does appear to be OK - there is an extremely short bit ot track between the pads, and the other end of the capacitor appears to connect to a ground fill, which matches the schematic.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not pretty and has obviously been shoe-horned in there by a lazy board designer. Electrically it is fine, according to your schematic, and once assembled it will not matter.

However, I have my doubts that an automated through hole insertion machine can handle the clearance between the parts. One or the other may need to be hand inserted.

Looking elsewhere I see a few mistakes with this board that was obviously not designed by anyone experienced in assembly. In particular C27 is located on the backside under a through hole component, IC4,  making it rather difficult to solder and interfering with the underside of IC4.

The radial capacitors also look like the hole spacing is wrong. That's a perfect recipe for broken capacitors.

If that was my PCB designer, it would be the last time I used them.

Comment: I think the radial caps may have preformed leads, hence the wonky spacing.